# Editing opengraph object that connected to an approved action

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

What will happen if i will edit object/aggregation that connected to an approved action?
Will it drop my approval?
I want to add more properties to the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing will happen, it will just add this object to the action. You will not lose your original approval.

Comment: I have edited some of my approved actions and objects and its working great, thank you!